# docker compose not starting 2 applications in 2 different location on same server

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have UAT and production setup on same server with identical code only the backend service is exposed on different ports.

i use the docker-compose up --build to start the application
but i am unable to start the uat and production application at same time.

first i go to the uat folder and run docker-compose up --build the application starts and same is visible in docker ps as well

but then i go to prod folder and issue docker-compose up --build it starts the service but the uat service goes down automatically
ideally when the code is in 2 different places it should behave as 2 different application and should be independent but its not happening.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  webbackend:
    build: .
    network_mode: "host"
    container_name: atms-webapp-backend-test
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    command:
      "python3.7 app.py --port=5002"
#      "gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 utootuweb.wsgi:application"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.16.0
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
WORKDIR /code/frontend
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
# RUN npm install -g serve
# RUN serve -s build

# RUN yarn
# RUN yarn build

# # Upgrade installed packages
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
# # Python package management and basic dependencies
#
# RUN apt-get install -y curl python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-distutils curl
# # node install
# RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
# RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
# # npm install
# RUN apt install -y npm
# RUN npm install -g npm@latest
#


# Python package management and basic dependencies

RUN apt-get install -y curl python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-distutils
# Register the version in alternatives
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
# Set python 3 as the default python
RUN update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.7

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.7 python3.7-dev python3-pip python3.7-venv libgl1
RUN apt-get install -y git

# update pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3.7 -m pip install wheel
# build frontend
# WORKDIR /code/frontend
#
# RUN npm install
# RUN npm run build
# install backend code
WORKDIR /code
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code/backend
CMD ["python3" ,"app.py"]
```

i have the same code base in 2 folders uat and prod
only the port is different

docker --version

Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636

docker-compose --version

docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

I changed the container name in docker-compose.yml to unique name for uat and prod as well just to make sure that container name is not the issue

Comment: something similar problem discussed here also but no answer
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-use-multiple-containers-from-the-same-image/84552

Comment: Are you using same service name for both? Try to rename `webbackend` to `webbackend1` and `webbackend2` and it should be ok. Otherwise It would be something in your code base...